# How to add a custom service to ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

I want to add a custom service to ActiveStorage because I want to overwrite the `url` method of the [ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e970d15211a8efd7349ff0e90d44d887b85793c2/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb) service so I can use a CloudFront CDN in front of my S3 bucket. I think I will not need the `presigned_url` params, I will just need the key, because the CloudFront instance will have full read access to the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a class in the `ActiveStorage::Service` namespace that subclasses `ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service`. Override the methods you want to override. For example:

```
# lib/active_storage/service/cloudfront_s3_service.rb 
require "active_storage/service/s3_service"

class ActiveStorage::Service::CloudfrontS3Service < ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service
  def url(key, **)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Refer to your custom service in `config/storage.yml`:

```
production:
  service: CloudfrontS3
  access_key_id: ""
  secret_access_key: ""
  region: ""
  bucket: ""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @george, I was just wondering why does DiskService use directories derived from the key, and S3 doesn't?

Comment: @PRWhitehead, most modern filesystems don’t limit the number of files in a single directory, but some encounter performance issues with directories containing more than ~30,000 files, which complicates deletion by prefix, system maintenance, backups, etc.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and the time you spent on ActiveStorage.

Comment: this is a bit vague and missing some details for rails 6. the process in rails 6 is a bit different.

Comment: On Rails 6 I had to stumble into the solution, since Zeitwork adds some steps to the process. The custom service MUST live in the namespace specified (active_storage/service), anywhere else will yield unexpected results. You also need to specify the service in application.rb & add the path to load your file     ```config.active_storage.service = :cloudfront_s3
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib', 'active_storage', 'service')```
 Lastly, you'll need to add a class stub to your new service `class CloudfrontS3Service < ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service; end`

Comment: Wanted to followup here that my above comment is adding cruft that isn't needed. There's no need to add to the eager_load_paths, nor is the stub of a class. What led me to this was without all of that, when attempting to load the class in Rails console would result in a class not found error. ActiveStorage auto-loads the class for us when it's needed.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone thats interested, I had a similar issue where by I wanted to use the same flat, single bucket storage, that the `S3Service` uses. Its simple enough once you know how:

```
require "active_storage/service/disk_service"

# S3 uses a flat folder structure, so mimic that so we an sync files and databases
module ActiveStorage
  class Service
    class FlatDiskService < DiskService
      private

      def folder_for(_key)
        "/"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the config is as follows:

```
local:
   service: FlatDisk
   root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Edit: I've updated the answer with the amended version that works in Rails 6.

Comment: Note there's more to it than this for Rails 6

Comment: Could you post some code so we could see the differences, as the example above has been working with Rails 5 and 6

Comment: Well there's the question of _where_ this file lives, and how it's included. If it's in `lib` (like most online examples show), then Zeitwerk complains that your file isn't defining an expected const. I'm probably doing something wrong, but none of the online examples I've seen fully explain everything that's needed. Leaves implementation details open to interpretation.

Comment: See my other comment above. The Zeitwerk error was introduced by adding the file to eager_load paths in config, removing that solves the issue.