# Rails ActiveStorage store to specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to create more specific paths to active storage files? What I need:
Currently we store some content in `/storage`, but what we want is to store these files in a more dimensional way. So, for instance, `user_files/#{Apartment::Tenant.current}/people/#{user_id}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on activestorage 6.0.21 and activestorage_direct_disk 0.3.2, also based on [How to add a custom service to ActiveStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782477/how-to-add-a-custom-service-to-activestorage). AS has been "improved" in the meanwhile, you can probably work out a different way to do it, but if after a couple weeks you get frustrated and sick of trying to get it to work, you can probably resort to something like this:

```
# lib/set_direct_disk_service_path.rb
module SetCurrentDomainName
    def set_domain_name(d)
        self.domain_name = d
    end
end

ActiveStorage::Current.class_eval { include SetCurrentDomainName }

module SetDirectDiskServiceRoot
    def initialize(p:, public: false, **options)
        @root = Rails.root.join("public", p)
        @public_root = p
        @public_root.prepend('/') unless @public_root.starts_with?('/')
    end

    def current_domain_name
        ActiveStorage::Current.domain_name
    end

    def folder_for(key)
        # output your path here.
    end
end
```

You can set different variables in your ApplicationController in a before_action hook. I use a multi-tenant scheme of my own because apartment didn't fit the bill, so I pass the tenant domain name from within the application controller.

Comment: Thanks @Nick M. What I ended up doing was simple once we decided that we didn't need to get down to the /people level in the path. In storage.yml, I simply changed the the root line to `<%= Rails.root.join("user_files", Apartment::Tenant.current, "storage") %>` which give me the new user_files path I needed and also passes in the current tenant.